# Intermediate results from recursion

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming, generator

I have a problem where I need to produce something which is naturally computed recursively, but where I also need to be able to interrogate the intermediate steps in the recursion if needed.

I know I can do this by passing and mutating a list or similar structure. However, this looks ugly to me and I'm sure there must be a neater way, e.g. using generators. What I would ideally love to be able to do is something like:

```
intermediate_results = [f(x) for x in range(T)]
final_result = intermediate_results[T-1]
```

in an efficient way. While my solution is not performance critical, I can't justify the massive amount of redundant effort in that first line. It looks to me like a generator would be perfect for this except for the fact that `f` is fundamentally much more suited to recursion in my case (which at least in my mind is the complete opposite of a generator, but maybe I'm just not thinking far enough outside of the box).

Is there a neat Pythonic way of doing something like this that I just don't know about, or do I just need to just capitulate and pollute my function `f` by passing it an `intermediate_results` list which I then mutate as a side-effect?

Comment: Can `f(x)` use memoization? If so, the memory table can be interrogated to get the intermediate results.

Comment: You can make an additional function, like a `logger` that will log the results of whatever values are passed to it. This `logger` can be ugly, however your recursion function will contain just a call to this `logger`  with value to be logged passed as a parameter, which would look much cleaner.

Comment: I know this question is already answered, but let me wonder anyway. Do you really need ALL intermediate results AFTER the final result is calculated? If it's not so, then memoization might not be the best solution, it would be better to play with logic of the program a bit

Comment: @heinwol thanks for your comment - I'd be interested to know what you think the alternatives are. The only options I can see are memoizing vs. writing the intermediate results to some variable. Memoizing is a much better fit for my use case out of those two options but I'm always open to further suggestions!

Comment: @user6282181 well, could you answer my question then, please?) It's really difficult to give a general answer. So enlighten me a bit about the nature of your algorithm.

Comment: @heinwol My problem is one where I have a number of functions which apply in some order to an initial value repeatedly. For example, f(x) = g(x) + a, g(x) = h(x) - b, and h(x) = f(x-1) * (1+c), with some initial boundary condition like f(0) = 0. The specifics of these functions are not defined in advance but the use case will to call, say, f(10). However it will sometimes be necessary, if f(10) turns out to be counterintuitive, to then view the results of g(10), h(10), f(9), g(9)... So yes, this intermediate inspection will only be needed after the result is computed, and only sometimes.

Comment: @heinwol Just for a bit of further context - this kind of thing is extremely simple to do with a spreadsheet. I would just set up a column for each function and the intermediate results will come out naturally. There are other drawbacks of using a spreadsheet that I want to avoid but being able to naturally see the intermediate results for a recursive calculation like that is really nice. I was hopeful that I could do something like that with a dataframe but it does not seem straightforward to do even with my highly simplified example above; at least not without calculating everything first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a generic solution for you using a decorator. We create a `Memoize` class which stores the results of previous times the function is executed (including in recursive calls). If the arguments given have already been seen, the cached versions are used to quickly lookup the result.

The custom class has the benefit over an `lru_cache` in that you can see the results.

```py
from functools import wraps

class Memoize:
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = {}

    def save(self, fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(*args):
            if args not in self.store:
                self.store[args] = fun(*args)
            return self.store[args]
        return wrapper

m = Memoize()

@m.save
def fibo(n):
    if n <= 0: return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else: return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

Then after running different things you can see what the cache contains. When you run future function calls, `m.store` will be used as a lookup so calculation doesn't need to be redone.

```
>>> f(8)
21
>>> m.store
{(1,): 1,
 (0,): 0,
 (2,): 1,
 (3,): 2,
 (4,): 3,
 (5,): 5,
 (6,): 8,
 (7,): 13,
 (8,): 21}
```

You could modify the `save` function to use the name of the function and the args as the key, so that multiple function results can be stored in the same `Memoize` class.

Comment: This would actually be perfect, but unfortunately I couldn't get the decorator to work as written. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (it's not that fibo uses f in the recursion as I tested my own function as well).

Comment: Whoops, good spot on the naming. Are you just copying and pasting above, and that's not working? Or it only doesn't work for your own function. If the latter, is your function simple enough to share?

Comment: I actually can't get it to work with what you've written, even with the correction. I get a type error: 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: Ah so sorry. I copied the wrong thing from my terminal. Was missing a return statement. Try now.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for this. As much as I like the lightweight lru_cache method from the other respondent I think this is going to save me from needing to manually recalculate everything that I want to see, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: This is basically the behind-the-scenes implementation of the `lru_cache`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your existing solution that makes many "redundant" calls to f, but employ the use of function caching to save the results to previous calls to f.
In other words, when f(x1) is called, it's input arguments and corresponding return values are saved, and the next time it is called, the result is simply pulled from the cache

see [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for the standard library solution to this

ie:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
intermediate_results = [f(x) for x in range(T)]
final_result = intermediate_results[T-1]
```

Note,  however, f must be a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (no side-effects, 1-to-1 mapping) for this to work properly

Comment: This looks like the neatest solution to me, especially since I know my functions will be pure (part of the reason I wanted to avoid the other solutions I thought of). I'll give some time for other answers to flow in before I mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Having considered your comments, I'll now try to give another perspective on the problem.

So, let's consider a concrete example:

```
def f(x):
    a = 2
    return g(x) + a if x != 0 else 0
def g(x):
    b = 1
    return h(x) - b
def h(x):
    c = 1/2
    return f(x-1)*(1+c)
```

#### I

First of all, it should be mentioned that (in our particular case) the algorithm has form of: `f(x) = p(f(x - 1))` for some `p`. It follows that `f(x) = p^x(f(0)) = p^x(0)`. That means we should just apply `p` to `0` `x` times to get the desired result, which can be done in an iterative process, so this *can* be written without recursion. Though I believe that your real case is much harder. Moreover, it would be too boring and uninformative to stop here)

#### II

Generally speaking, we can divide all possible solutions into two groups: the ones that require refactoring (i.e. rewriting functions f, g, h) and the ones that do not. I have little to offer from the latter one (and I don't think anyone can). Consider the following, however:

```
def fk(x, k):
    a = 2
    return k(gk(x, k) + a if x != 0 else 0)
def gk(x, k):
    b = 1
    return k(hk(x, k) - b)
def hk(x, k):
    c = 1/2
    return k(fk(x-1, k)*(1+c))

def printret(x):
    print(x)
    return x

f(4, printret) # see what happens
```

Inspired by [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), but that's totally not it.

What's the point? It's something between your idea of passing a list to write down all the computations and memoizing. This k carries additional behavior with it, such as printing or writing to list (you can make a function that writes to some list, why not?). But if you look carefully you'll see that it lefts inner code of these functions practically untouched (only input and output to function are affected), so one can produce a decorator associated with a function like `printret` that does essentially the same thing for f, g, h.

- **Pros:** no need to modify code, much more flexible than passing a list, no additional work (like in memoizing).
- **Cons:** Impure (printing or modifying sth), not so flexible as we would like.

#### III

Now let's see how modifying function bodies can help. Don't be afraid of what's written below, take your time and play with that thing a little.

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, lst, cur_val):
        self.lst = lst
        self.cur_val = cur_val
    
    def bind(self, f):
        res = f(self.cur_val)
        return Logger([self.cur_val] + res.lst + self.lst, res.cur_val)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Logger( " + repr({'value' : self.cur_val,'lst' : self.lst}) + " )" 

def unit(x):
    return Logger([], x)

# you can also play with lala
def lala(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return unit(1)
    else:
        return lala(x - 1).bind(lambda y: unit(2*y))


def f(x):
    a = 2
    if x == 0:
        return unit(0)
    else:
        return g(x).bind(lambda y: unit(y + a))
def g(x):
    b = 1
    return h(x).bind(lambda y: unit(y - b))
def h(x):
    c = 1/2
    return f(x-1).bind(lambda y: unit(y*(1+c)))

f(4) # see for yourself
```

`Logger` is called a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). I'm not very familiar with this concept myself, but I guess I'm doing everything right) f, g, h are functions that take a number and return a `Logger` instance. `Logger`'s `bind` takes in a function (like f) and returns `Logger` with new value (computed by f) and updated 'logs'. The key point - as I see it - is the ability to do whatever we want with collected functions in the order the resulting value was calculated.

#### Afterword

I'm not at all some kind of 'guru' of functional programming, I believe I'm missing a lot of things here. But what I've understood is that functional programming is about *inversing the flow* of the program. That's why, for instance, I totally agree with your opinion about generators being opposed to functional programming. When we use generator `gen` in, say, function `func`, we yield values one by one *to* `func` and `func` does sth with them in e.g. a loop. The functional approach would be to make `gen` a function taking `func` as a parameter and make `func` perform computations on 'yielded' values. It's like `gen` and `func` exchanged their places. So the flow is inversed! And there are plenty of other ways of inversing the flow. Monads are one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your in-depth response - I have some experience with Haskell so a lot of this makes sense to me and it's part of the reason why I went out of my way to avoid just passing lists around to functions that shouldn't really depend on them in the general case. I'll have a play with this and see if I can apply it to my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

itertools islice gets a generator, start value and stop value. it will give you the elements between the start value and stop value as a generator. if islice is not clear you can check the docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

```py
intermediate_result = map(f, range(T))
final_result = next(itertools.islice(intermediate_result, start=T-1, stop=T))
```